# Is there a fix for passing string as a model to an MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the MVC 4.0 and ran into a case where I cannot get to the correct view due to my model being a string object.

The following attempts have all failed the same way, that is the browser tries to route my call to a view with the name of the contents of the model.

Attempt 1

```
return View("Image", (object)key);
```

Attempt 2

```
return View(viewName: "Image", model: (object)key);
```

Attempt 3

```
return View("Image", "Image", (object)key);
```

Attempt 4

```
return View(viewName: "Image", masterName: "Image", model: (object)key);
```

Error: The view 'My Data' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations...

I got my attempted solution from http://www.heartysoft.com/aspnet-mvc-gotcha-string-model

Comment: did you try: return View("Image", model: key);  ?

Comment: @StevePy, that fails too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something other than System.String. Perhaps MvcHtmlString like this:

```
return View("Image", "Image", MvcHtmlString.Create(key));
```

Or just create a model class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Either one should work. Of course that means changing your view possibly but not much.

Comment: Failed:
    return View("Image", "Image", MvcHtmlString.Create(key));
Creating a new viewmodel worked

Comment: At this point, I have to reaudit my routes to see if there is any reason the MvcHtmlString failed. But I am good otherwise.